# Are FILESTREAM datatypes stored in the .mdf file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, filestream, sql-server-2008-r2

Are FILESTREAM datatypes stored in the .mdf file?

Can they be stored anywhere else like a separate directory?

Thanks Paul

Comment: FILESTREAM entry in Books Online alone is sufficient to answer this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are already stored on the filesystem, the only thing in the `.mdf` file will be a reference to the file location.

From [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx):

> FILESTREAM integrates the SQL Server Database Engine with an NTFS file system by storing varbinary(max) binary large object (BLOB) data as files on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

You can control where the `FILESTREAM` objects on a **partitioned** table are stored by [using the `FILESTREAM_ON` attribute in your `CREATE TABLE` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

> `FILESTREAM_ON { partition_scheme_name
>   | filegroup | "default" }`
>
> Specifies
>   the filegroup for FILESTREAM data.
>
> If the table contains FILESTREAM data
>   and the table is partitioned, the
>   FILESTREAM_ON clause must be included
>   and must specify a partition scheme of
>   FILESTREAM filegroups. This partition
>   scheme must use the same partition
>   function and partition columns as the
>   partition scheme for the table;
>   otherwise, an error is raised.